# Parse XML Data from URL

Tags: php, xml

I have searched the site and found many resources to help me load and XML file to parse, however after following some of the examples, I can still not get this to work. What am I missing?

thanks

```
<?php
$url = 'http://api.l5srv.net/job_search/api/web/find_jobs.srv?CID=2239&SID=u9xcvY234AA09&format=XML&q=Sales&l=95054&r=25&s=relevance&a=2014-09-30&start=1&limit=8&highlight=off&userip=25.158.22.121&useragent=Mozilla%2F5.0';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");

var_dump($xml);
?>
```

Comment: What happens currently?

Comment: its says 'feed not loading'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code coming from this server is not valid XML. Try this:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://api.l5srv.net/job_search/api/web/find_jobs.srv?CID=2239&SID=u9xcvY234AA09&format=XML&q=Sales&l=95054&r=25&s=relevance&a=2014-09-30&start=1&limit=8&highlight=off&userip=25.158.22.121&useragent=Mozilla%2F5.0';

    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = '<' . '?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?' . '>' . str_replace(array("&lt;", "&gt;"), array("<", ">"), $data);

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($data) or die("feed not loading");

    var_dump($xml);
```

Comment: Hi, I just put this in my script and it still  no go, any thoughts? thanks for help/

Comment: The script above is working for me in a sandbox - can you update your post with your new code?

Comment: Hi, its works, made a typo error, thanks for the help. So the reason this happened was because they person who provided me the code, does not have valid XML?

Comment: Yes, the code that comes off of the server has been HTML encoded, so the '<' and '>' characters have been encoded to '&lt;' and '&gt;' (HTML codes). They have also missed out `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Even it might work, the character encoding of the HTML is different. Use a HTML parser (e.g. **DOMDocument**)  and then load it as HTML and extract the XML. No need to manually punch holes into that string.

Answer (score 2):

You're most likely confusing what you see in the browser under that URL with an XML document.

What you have at the URL

> `http://api.l5srv.net/job_search/api/web/find_jobs.srv?CID=2239&SID=u9xcvY234AA09&format=XML&q=Sales&l=95054&r=25&s=relevance&a=2014-09-30&start=1&limit=8&highlight=off&userip=25.158.22.121&useragent=Mozilla%2F5.0`

is not an XML document. When you request that URL and you look into the response headers, you can see that it is a HTML document:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="IDC CON TEL CUR DEV SAM IND"
Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2015 15:50:46 GMT
Content-Language: en-US
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: X-Mapping-gjinjpae=F462690912B62A0C5476B15FCDB01A81; path=/
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=BC6666D2A357FB969A60E05E67B0888C; Path=/
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=700D01B2F92909260A05215F86AB8EE5; Path=/
Content-Length: 7147
```

You can also easily verify that with your browser by making use of the *view source* feature in your browser or by seeing, that the XML is not displayed "pretty".

However `simplexml_load_file` expects a well-formed XML document. In your case the main problem you've got is missing error handling. As you interact with a remote system, error handling is crucial for stable use, so make it part of your script:

- [Dealing with XML errors (SimpleXML - PHP Manual)](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-errors)

Next to that, as it's an HTML document and not an XML document, you need to parse it with a HTML parser - not an XML parser. So don't try with an XML parser at that stage, use a HTML parser first.

- [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/367456) (Reference Q&A)

***Edit:***

The problem with that service is only when you request XML format. If you change the format parameter to JSON (`&format=JSON`) you can parse the data straight-away despite the wrong response content-type given:

```
$url = 'http://api.l5srv.net/job_search/api/web/find_jobs.srv?CID=2239&SID=u9xcvY234AA09&format=JSON&q=Sales&l=95054&r=25&s=relevance&a=2014-09-30&start=1&limit=8&highlight=off&userip=25.158.22.121&useragent=Mozilla%2F5.0';

$result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

print_r($result);
```

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [response] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [query] => Sales
                    [location] => 95054
                    [highlight] => off
                    [totalresults] => 25406
                    [start] => 1
                    [end] => 9
                    [radius] => 25
                    [pageNumber] => 0
                    [results] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [jobtitle] => Sales
                                    [zip] => 95101
                                    [company] => Commercial Janitorial Company
                                    [city] => San Jose
                                    [state] => CA
                                    [country] => US
                                    [date] => 2015-07-14
                                    [url] => http://api.l5srv.net/job_search/api/web/get_job.srv?token=3aeyzv6V2SA%2BKYF5lzqWmxyivVwoE3LFernO291sVVpLbWCG9bBAbVO%2BCGXuN1V%2F9QMmDY3KeK5iYg2phrtjypXtQ82Jngf1q8zQIzix14EuBlSL96sqjffsuHozTZ4SJ6Mf%2B%2BVwRrC65gRtKxH6wg0F50WEZtnD9Xv0%2Bxc2GMhFMszKNEOyrfCNg5YTn%2Flj
                                    [snippet] => Company Description:

We are a Christian owned janitorial company doing business here in the Bay Area for nearly 40 years. You do not have to be Christian to work for us.
We operate in a fast paced, f
                                    [onmousedown] => l5_trk(this)
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [jobtitle] => Sales
[...]
```

Comment: There might be even a request header missing, looking into it.

Comment: Okay, no header problem, just most likely a very disturbed server.

Comment: @DavidMaldonado: Jup, that service is a total mess. It can't deliver XMl properly, but it does deliver the JSON. I've edited the anser and gave an example.

Comment: yes i seew hat you mean, thats a great tip, thanks for help!